# Multiple DBContext, Include some models in other database context model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In our projects, we use UnitOfWork Design Pattern.

In UnitOfWork, our DatabaseContext is hide from outside the project.

In Server Project (WebAPI), we want use Identity for User Authentication and Authorization. in this case, cant access DabaseContext, because its hide behind the UnitOfWork.

We Add new Database Context for Identity. and its public to access it from server project.

Now there is problem with join some models in different database context:
Identity tables exist in IdentityDatabaseContext with custom Scheme: "identity"
Application tables exist in DatabaseContext with general scheme: "dbo"
There is a Model (like News) in Application that have a property of identity.User

```
UnitOfWork
    DatabseContext
        News
          NewsId
          Title
          ...
          CreateUser -> CreateUser is a User from Identity (from IdentityDatabaseContext)
```

Code:

```
      NewRepository.GetAll().Include(x=>x.CreateUser)
```

If we use Include "User" in News, we got error:

> The expression 'p.User' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation,
> since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To
> target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t =>
> ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as
> Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by
> composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take
> operations. For more information on including related data, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Comment: It's just a wrong design. EF `DbContext` represents a database. So if entities are stored in one and the same database and have relationships, they must be part of one and the same `DbContext`. Period. All other is just unresolvable issues. Also hiding the `DbContext` which IS a UOW (and `DbSet<T>` is repository) behind another UOW/Repository abstractions is considered "anti-pattern" because just creates issues without providing real benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're decomposing your app at the repository level, which is not the right level to compartmentalize your domain.
It's better to modularize your app into Bounded Context(in terms of DDD) if need be, if not stick to a single instance of DbContext at least for a [Bounded Context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html).